# How can I get Javascript to display the errors that are in my JavaScript code and why doesn't my submit button work?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

```js
var $ = function(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

var submitForm = function() {
  var FirstName = $("firstName").value;
  var OrderNumber = $("orderNumber").value;
  var DateOfOrder = $("date_of_order").value;
  var EmailAddress = $("email_address").value;
  var isValid = true;

  if (FirstName !== "Cherry" && FirstName !== "Micheal" &&
    FirstName !== "Sandra" && FirstName !== "Cookie") {
    $("firstname_error").firstChild.nodeValue =
      "This person does not exist.";
    isValid = false;
  } else {
    $("firstname_error").firstChild.nodeValue = "";
  }

  if (OrderNumber !== 3134 && OrderNumber !== 4234 &&
    OrderNumber !== 9234 && OrderNumber !== 3566) {
    $("orderNumber_error").firstChild.nodeValue = "Invalid Order Number.";
    isValid = false;
  } else {
    $("orderNumber_error").firstChild.nodeValue = "";
  }

  if (DateOfOrder !== 12 - 07 - 23 && DateOfOrder !== 15 - 04 - 24 &&
    DateOfOrder !== 16 - 02 - 01 && DateOfOrder !== 14 - 01 - 12) {
    $("date_of_order_error").firstChild.nodeValue = "Date doesn't exist in
    system";
    isValid = false;
  } else {
    $("date_of_order_error").firstChild.nodeValue = "";
  }

  if (EmailAddress !== "cherryjackson@gmail.com" && EmailAddress !== "michealroberts@yahoo.com" && EmailAddress !== "sandrabell@hotmail.com" && EmailAddress !== "cookiedanny@outlook.com") {
    $("email_address_error").firstChild.nodeValue = "The email doesn't exist";
    isValid = false;
  } else {
    $("email_address_error").firstChild.nodeValue = "";
  }
  if (isValid) {
    //submit the form if all entries are valid
    $("cookie_form").submit();
  }
}
window.onload = function() {
  $("form_submission").onclick = submitForm;
  $("email_address").focus();
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #FBFBE8;
}
/* Tells HTML5 to find the font-type-face that my OS has and then use that for heading 1
  and also centers the first heading */

h1 {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
/* Tells HTML5 to use any of the font-types for my first paragraph in HTML source file
   if one is not available. Also clears some white space 
   from the left margin of the paragraph and finally tells it to give that paragraph
   a size of 20 pixels. */

p {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
label {
  float: left;
  width: 11em;
  text-align: right;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #800000;
}
input {
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}
span {
  color: red;
}
.field_set_1 {
  border-color: purple;
  border-style: solid;
}
#form_submission {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
legend {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: blue;
}
/* All of the classes are just for positioning and floating the four 
same images around the form input information   */

.Wrap1 {
  float: right;
  margin: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.Wrap2 {
  float: left;
  margin: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<h1>Cookie Order Form</h1>
<p>This form is a cookie order form for customers that purchased cookies from Daron's Cookies Company and the following below must be filled out in order for each customer to receive a final message that tells them when their order will be ready.</p>

<IMG class="Wrap1" SRC="cookie.gif" alt="cookie">
<IMG class="Wrap2" SRC="cookie.gif" alt="cookie2">


<!--The customer will be sent to the HTML page named "submit form.html" after they
click the "Submit this Form" button. The code below does this. -->
<div>
  <form id="cookie_form" name="cookie_form" action="submit form.html" method="get">
    <fieldset class="field_set_1">
      <!-- Below sets the title of the form-->
      <legend>Customer Order Form Information:</legend>

      <!-- Creates the first left label to specify what should be placed in the text box
the the right of the label. The rest below does the same.-->
      <label for="firstName">First Name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="firstName" name="firstName">
      <span id="firstname_error">*</span>
      <br>

      <label for="orderNumber">Order Number:</label>
      <input type="text" id="orderNumber" name="orderNumber">
      <span id="orderNumber_error">*</span>
      <br>

      <label for="date_of_order">Date of Order:</label>
      <input type="text" id="date_of_order" name="date_of_order">
      <span id="date_of_order_error">*</span>
      <br>

      <label for="email_address">Email Address:</label>
      <input type="text" id="email_address" name="email_address">
      <span id="email_address_error">*</span>
      <br>

      <label>&nbsp;</label>

      <input type="button" id="form_submission" value="Submit this Form">
    </fieldset>

  </form>

</div>
<div class="clearfix">
</div>
<IMG class="Wrap1" SRC="cookie.gif" alt="cookie">
<IMG class="Wrap2" SRC="cookie.gif" alt="cookie2">
```

I have been working on this for hours. I am trying to figure out why won't my JavaScript code won't display the error message in the form when customers enter invalid order Numbers, incorrect order dates, or names that system can't detect. etc. Can someone pinpoint in the right direction of why my code doesn't work for the form and why won't it go to the next page when I click on the 'submit this form' button.

Comment: Have a look in the console that exists in dev tools of all modern browsers - https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/ It will likely have some useful information for you to help pinpoint the issue

Comment: Have you [checked your console?](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/getting-started-with-javascript/714/using-console-log) You'll see an error you need to address.

Comment: The broad nature of this question suggests that this is an excellent opportunity for you to become familiarized with your browser's debugging tools.  Open those tools in your browser (usually by pressing F12 in most browsers) and take a look at what's there.  The "console" will display any JavaScript errors, for example, or can be used to manually execute JavaScript code on the page for testing.  Additionally, the debugger can be used to place breakpoints in your code which will pause execution and allow you to step through the code, line by line, as it executes and observe the logic/values.

Comment: I have already answered your earlier question and provided working code here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42031319/why-isnt-my-form-submit-button-not-going-to-a-next-page-when-i-click-on-it?noredirect=1#comment71237117_42031319 Please don't repost the same question, just add comments to the original.

Comment: Scott Marcus - You reworked my project into something more complicated than what I wanted. I should be able to display the same results with my if-else statements. How can I do that?

Comment: Already voted to close this question as too broad, but it should *definitely* be closed as a duplicate of the one @ScottMarcus just linked.

Comment: @Joe: This doesn't do what you think it does: `DateOfOrder !== 12 - 07 - 23`.  12, 7, and 23 are integers being subtracted from each other there.  (I'm also not entirely sure on the order of operations for that expression.)  Also, you appear to have a multi-line string, which might not be valid in JavaScript.  Honestly, your best bet is to start familiarizing yourself with a debugger.  Another user already put in significant effort to help you in your original question, and you appear to have rejected that help.  Given that, we can't really help you with something this broad.

Comment: @Joe Did you read through **all** my code comments? You weren't using a `submit` button and I changed that... The `if/then` wasn't the only issue.

Comment: Scott Marcus I sorry about that. I should really learn to take a break

Answer (score 0):

The value coming from your input elements doesn't match to orderNumber and date of birth. puting them in quotes (inside condition check) will solve the issue.

```
if(DateOfOrder !== "12-07-23" && DateOfOrder !== "15-04-24" &&
   DateOfOrder !== "16-02-01" &&  DateOfOrder !== "14-01-12")
{....}
```

[Working Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/1N45chX4nCMnpYqGdj5G?p=preview)

Comment: amansoni211 the code that put on separate website didn't work for me when I used it. it's still not displaying the error messages if invalid input is put in the boxes

Comment: It worked  amansoni211, but how do you get the 'submit this button' to go to the next page.